# AWS Code Build Error : Cannot connect to docker daemon

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I was trying to build docker image using aws code build service and then push it to ECR. Commands which i used for it in `"buildspec.yml"` is specified in below.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
        docker: 18
 pre_build:
      - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
      - REPOSITORY_URI=XXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/devopswebbuild
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
```

But i am getting error during build process, docker command is unable to connect to docker daemon.Please help me to solve these issue.

Docker build project configuration details is given below:

[image: code]

Build error details is given below:

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am answering my own question, so it may help some one who is getting same issue. Solution was pretty straightforward, i need to check the privilaged tab which i didn't notice.

[image]

Solution :

1. From the AWS CodeBuild Console, select the Build Project.
2. Select the 'Edit' dropdown from the top-right corner, and select the 'Environment' option.
3. Within the 'Edit Environment' page, select 'Override image'. After this, scroll down to find the 'Privileged' option and select it.
4. Select 'Update Environment' to ensure that the property is updated.

Comment: Thanks for including the answer, because I just ran into the same thing.  :highfive:

Comment: Ran into the same problem, your solution worked, thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

If using CDK, you will have to set `docker_enabled_for_synth` flag in CodePipeline. Also, you may need to make a manual deployment (cdk deploy), since pipeline' self mutation didn't work for me.

```python
pipeline = pipelines.CodePipeline(
            scope=self,
            id="SomeCodePipeline",
            ...
            docker_enabled_for_self_mutation=True,
            docker_enabled_for_synth=True,  # enable docker builds
        )
```